# Open Link In a different profile in Edge

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

Chrome offers an option to open a link in a different profile while one is in another profile. I was looking for a similar option in Edge and came across [this article](https://www.timschaeps.be/post/open-link-microsoft-edge-profiles/) which suggests using the `Open As` option. The problem is that I don't see this option in the Edge that I'm using.

[image]

Is there any setting that needs to be enabled or has this option been removed altogether from Edge?

Edge Version:

> Version 120.0.2210.91 (Official build) (64-bit)

Windows version:

> Edition   Windows 11 Enterprise
>
> Version   22H2
>
> Installed on  ‎23-‎09-‎2023
>
> OS build  22621.2715 Experience
>
> Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22677.1000.0

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge has only help with using multiple profiles with the
Automatic profile switching option.
This option is enabled in
*Settings > Profiles > Profile preferences > Account based profile switching*.

Its effect is that once a website is opened using a certain profile,
Edge will in the future offer for any link to the site to switch
to this profile if the current profile is different:

[image]

If this doesn't work for you, I don't know at the moment of another
solution than manually switching profiles.

Reference :
[How to automatically switch Profiles for specific sites in Edge](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-automatically-switch-profiles-for-specific-sites-in-edge).

Comment: As a Chromium browser you can specify which profile to use as a launch argument.

Comment: did you mean to leave the name and email visible to all in the screenshot ?

Comment: @1NN That's not his real profile :) It's available on [this blog page](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/04/30/automatic-profile-switching/) by MSDN.

Comment: @1NN: `contoso.com` is Microsoft's demo virtual company.